# How to decrease spacing between line of UILabel ( Swift )?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, line-spacing

Now, I trying to **decrease** a spacing between multiple line Label.
For my way I create function like this..

```
func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat) {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.0
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeight
    paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment

    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    if (self.attributedText != nil) {
        attrString.append( self.attributedText!)
    } else {
        attrString.append( NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!))
        attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: self.font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    }
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    self.attributedText = attrString
}
```

and use it by `myLabel.setLineHeight(0.7)`

For problem, It can decrease a line height ! but...It remain a extra space at the bottom of label.

[image]

I align my text to centered vertically to parent view but after I `setLineHeight` It won't center anymore.
Has anyone seen this problem?

For constraint of label v
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set line spacing from storyboard as well and keep the alignment as shown in following gif

[image]

Comment: thank you for you answer, but I didn't lock any constraint except left, right and vertically in container krub.